# Avoid screen lighting (wake up) when Notification received in lock mode in android

Tags: android

I am currently building an application, In which I want to avoid the screen lighting when I received any notification if my android mobile in lock state.

I am trying to find the solution but I couldn't get any way to do it.

I tried below code on `switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);`
but it's not working.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if ((notificationManager != null) && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);       
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_ENABLE_DO_NOT_DISTURB_SCREEN_FLASH);
    } else {
        if (b) {
            notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
        } else {
            notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
        }
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Don't have notification policy permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Can anyone will help me to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: First of all, you can only manage the notifications that are created by your application. If you want to disable the notifications for all applications, its not possible. Please clarify on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your instant reply...oh no..."I can not disable the notifications for all applications"...I think there should be a way to do this..but unfortunately we can't get that...any way thanks...

Answer (score -1):

Please add these lines to the starting of your Activity, before `setContentView` and after `super.onCreate`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

You can avoid `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` from flags.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but it not worked for me. I used it like this
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`


My lock screen still bling(lightning) when any notification arrive in lock state.

Comment: add this line to AndroidManifest.xml : android:showOnLockScreen="true" @Shweta

Comment: Still my Lock screen bling when notification arrive. By using `android:showOnLockScreen="true"` I can show that activity when notification arrived. I want to avoid the screen blinging(lightning) when any notification arrived. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: that is the default action by Android. In Some flavor like Redmi, there is by default enable this "wake Device on Notification". We can't handle this one.

Comment: Ohh no...I was testing it in Redmi and it not worked, I tested it in Sony Xperia and Samsung galaxy s5 just now but, it not work for "keep screen OFF when the notification arrived in lock state"..anyway thanks..@Harsh

Comment: Its opposite answer.